# Get random direction for object to move within a maze

Tags: c#, arraylist, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a few gameobject to randomly walk around a maze. I currently have it working properly, where the objects can go left/right/forward. The issue I am having is when the have the opportunity to go forward and left/right the always choose to turn left or right, they never choose to go forward, and I can not figure out why... What am I missing here?

```
public float speed;
public bool changed = false;
public bool forward, left, right;

protected Transform frontRaycast, leftRaycast, rightRaycast;

void Update(){
    if(!changed){
        forward = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, frontRaycast.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Wall"));
        left = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, leftRaycast.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Wall"));
        right = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, rightRaycast.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Wall"));

        List<int> possibleDirs = new List<int>();
        if(!forward){
            possibleDirs.Add(0);
        }
        if(!left){
            possibleDirs.Add(1);
        }
        if(!right){
            possibleDirs.Add(2);
        }
        int dir = 0;
        //Debug.Log(Random.Range(0, possibleDirs.Count));
        if(possibleDirs.Count > 0){
            dir = (int)possibleDirs[Random.Range(0, possibleDirs.Count)];
        }

        Debug.Log(dir);

        switch(dir){
            case 0:
                transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,0));
                break;
            case 1:
                transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,90));
                changed = true;
                Invoke("reset", 0.5f);
                break;
            case 2:
                transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,-90));
                changed = true;
                Invoke("reset", 0.5f);
                break;
        }
    }
    transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
}

void reset(){
    changed = false;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure possibleDirs has the "0" element in it? What makes you think its not working? As an aside, why on earth are you using ArrayList???

Comment: What would be better than array list?

Comment: How about a generic list (`List<T>`)?

Comment: I am using a list now, but it still isn't working..

Comment: I didn't think that it was your problem, its just considered bad practice to use it. My question still stands, nothing is obviously wrong with your code, so are you sure you never get into the "0" case?

Comment: looks like it is because I don't have `changed` and and `Invoke()` with in my `case 0`

Comment: That would explain why you don't *see* any result, but I wanted to make sure you actually got into the case before mentioning it. Seems like you are on the right track though. Good luck!

Comment: thanks! I got it all working!